# How to assign output of a complicated shell command to variable in Jinja in a Salt State

Tags: yaml, jinja2, escaping, salt-stack

I'm writing a Salt state where I have this shell command:

```
/path/to/directory/java/bin/./java -version 2>&1 | awk -F'java version' '{print $1}' | awk -F'\.' '{print $2; exit}'| tr -d '"'
```

which works when I run it as a script or directly in Bash in my server (the stdout is just a number like '_021'). I need to save that number in a Jinja variable so I can pass it into a function later in the state, but the problem is  the special characters and spaces and things are causing all kinds of escaping issues and Jinja or YAML isn't reading it correctly.

I've tried typical escaping using \, putting the command inside a `{% raw %}` block, surrounding it in triple quotes, using the `| safe` flag, I just cannot seem to get it to work...

In essence what I'm trying to do is this:

```
{% set minorVer = salt['cmd.run']("/path/to/directory/java/bin/./java -version 2>&1 | awk -F'java version' '{print $1}' | awk -F'\.' '{print $2; exit}'| tr -d '"' ")

My Function:
  cmd.run:
    - name: run the command with variable {{ minorVer }}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what are the errors now? I think you could start thinking about writing a little module or grain to build that value if it's not already there. Also you always need to give all the details of the issue

Comment: sorry about that! I've tried dozens things and each one returns a different error so I thought it would be hard to include. But I think they all ultimately trace back to some fundamental misunderstanding with Jinja or Yaml.

Comment: but I remember that I already have give you a working solution for the `cmd.run` call to get the version in another question. What's the issue now?

Comment: that solution didn't work for my command unfortunately, I got another similar error I believe "Jinja syntax error: expected token ',', got 'string 'java"

Comment: You could put this command in a shell script and run it from Salt, if that's an option.

Answer (score 1):

The correct escaping should be:

```py
'/path/to/directory/java/bin/./java -version 2>&1 | awk -F\'java version\' \'{print $1}\' | awk -F\'\\.\' \'{print $2; exit}\'| tr -d \'"\''
```

But it can all be avoided by doing the text processing in jinja, e.g.

```py
{% set version_out = salt["cmd.run"]("${JAVA_HOME}/java -version") %}
{% set version = version_out.splitlines()[0].split(" ")[2] | replace('"', '') %}
{% set minorVersion = version.split(".")[2] %}
```

Note also your processing won't work for a lot of java installations. I get these outputs, for example, where there is no "java version" or "_xxx":

```
openjdk version "11.0.20" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
openjdk version "11.0.20" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.20+8 (build 11.0.20+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.20+8 (build 11.0.20+8, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jinja to do string processing as OrangeDog suggested is a good solution. Alternatively you can put your commands into a file in your salt file server and run it using the `cmd.script` module (or state)

```
{%- set version = salt["cmd.script"]("salt://scripts/javaversion.sh") %}
```

Ultimately, depending on what you need the information for and how much complexity you are adding to the sls file, the best solution might be to write your own custom state module or execution module in python. Writing a state module is relatively simple depending on what you're doing and can really clean up a lot of unreadable jinja mixed with yaml.